# Delete repeating words in a string MASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, text-processing, masm32

I need to find all words repeated N times and delete them from string.

I don’t understand how to iterate through string and compare words in MASM32. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Like any other in-place filtering, with read and write pointers that both start at the start of the string.  Having variable-length objects (word = contiguous bytes separated by non-word characters) makes it more complicated to both copy them around and compare.

On top of that, you'll want to remember the end of the current and previous (or Nth-previous?) words so you can rewind the write pointer to effectively delete from the tail of the string.  Or something like that.

You might want an array (circular buffer) of word-end pointers so you can copy and compare at the same time.

Comment: @PeterCordes by pointers you mean ESI/EDI registers?

Comment: No, I mean 32-bit values that hold an address, like the value of a C variable like `char *lastword`.  You can store a pointer value anywhere, including memory.  You can only *dereference* it when it's in a register, but any register can be used in 32-bit addressing modes.  `cmp al, [ecx]` is valid, for example.  TL:DR: I was talking about pointer values, not the locations you might keep one.

Comment: Post answers as answers (and include the code inline, not as an external link, if you're willing to share it at all under the CC-by-SA copyright license that applies to SO posts.)  Don't make edits to the question that turn it into a non-question.  If you want a code-review of your code for improvements, post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've done the job. Here is some code. If you have some suggestions on how to improve the code feel free to tell me!

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
include masm32.inc
include kernel32.inc
includelib masm32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
temp db 10
msg1 db 10, 13, "Input string: ", 10, 13, 0
msg2 db 10, 13, "How many times should word be repeated? ", 10, 13, 0
msg_true db 10, 13, "TRUE", 10, 13, 0
msg_false db 10, 13, "FALSE", 10, 13, 0

move_to_next_word db 1
infinite_loop db 1
garbage dd ?

input_string db 128 dup(?)

input_string_len dd ?
remaining_string_len dd ?

word_buffer db 128 dup(?)

repeat_num db 10 dup(?)

current_word_ptr dd ?


; PROTOTYPES-----------------------------------------------------
find_space proto inp:ptr byte, len:dword
str_len proto inp:ptr byte, delimiter:byte
str_to_int proto inp:ptr byte
str_cmp proto str1:ptr byte, str2:ptr byte, delimiter:byte
delete_word proto word_start:dword, word_end:dword, word_len:dword
; ---------------------------------------------------------------

.code
main proc
invoke  StdOut, offset msg1
invoke  StdIn,  offset input_string, lengthof input_string
invoke  StdOut, offset msg2
invoke  StdIn,  offset repeat_num, lengthof repeat_num

invoke  str_to_int, offset repeat_num

    mov esi, offset input_string

    .while infinite_loop == 1

    pushad
invoke  str_len, offset input_string, 0
    mov input_string_len, ecx
    popad

invoke  str_len, esi, 0
    mov     remaining_string_len, ecx

invoke  find_space, esi, remaining_string_len
    mov current_word_ptr, esi

    .if ecx == 0
        jmp terminate
    .endif

    ; end of the current word
    push edi


    push esi
    push edi

    ; counter of duplicates
    xor edx, edx
    mov dl, 0

    mov edi, offset input_string
    dec edi
    mov ecx, input_string_len

.while ecx > 0
    inc edi
invoke  find_space, edi, ecx

invoke  str_cmp, current_word_ptr, esi, " "

    .if ebx == 1
    inc dl

    push esi ; word's start
    push edi ; word's end

    pushad
invoke  StdOut, offset msg_true
    popad

    .elseif ebx == 0
    pushad
invoke  StdOut, offset msg_false
    popad
    .endif
.endw

.if dl == repeat_num
    mov move_to_next_word, 0
    .while dl > 1
        pop edi
        pop esi
        inc edi
    invoke str_len, edi, 0
        dec edi

invoke  delete_word, esi, edi, ecx
        dec dl
    .endw

    ; delete first word

    pop edi
    pop esi

invoke str_len, edi, 0
    dec edi

invoke delete_word, esi, edi, ecx

.else
    .while dl > 0

    pop edi
    pop esi
    dec dl
    .endw
.endif

    pushad
invoke  StdOut, offset input_string
    popad

    .if move_to_next_word == 1
        ; get ptr to the next word
        pop esi
        inc esi
    .else
        mov move_to_next_word, 1
        pop garbage
    .endif
    .endw

terminate:

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp


; FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------------------
; esi - string start
; edi - string end
; ebx - word length
; ecx - length of the remaining string
find_space proc inp:ptr byte, len:dword
    mov     edi, inp
    mov     esi, inp
    mov     ecx, len
    mov     al, " "
    cld
repne   scasb
    dec     edi
    mov     ebx, edi
    sub     ebx, esi
    ret
find_space endp

;ecx - length of a string
str_len proc inp:ptr byte, delimiter:byte
    push edi
    push eax

    mov     edi, inp
    sub     ecx, ecx
    not     ecx ; ECX = -1, or 4,294,967,295
    mov     al, delimiter
    cld     
repne   scasb
    not     ecx
    dec     ecx

    pop eax
    pop edi
    ret
str_len endp

; convert string to int
str_to_int proc inp:ptr byte
    pushad 

    mov     ecx, 0
    mov     esi, inp
    cmp     byte ptr [esi + ecx], 0
    sub     byte ptr [esi + ecx], 48d ;
    inc     ecx

    popad
    ret
str_to_int endp

; if equal then     ebx = 1
; if not equal then ebx = 0
str_cmp proc str1:ptr byte, str2:ptr byte, delimiter:byte
.data
str1_len dd ?
str2_len dd ?

.code
    push eax
    push ecx
    push edi
    push esi

    mov     esi, str1
    mov     edi, str2
invoke  str_len, str1, delimiter ; ecx = length of str1
    mov     str1_len, ecx
invoke  str_len, str2, delimiter
    mov     str2_len, ecx

    cmp str1_len, ecx
    jne notequal

repe    cmpsb
    je  equal
notequal:
    mov ebx, 0
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    ret
equal:
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    mov ebx, 1
    ret
str_cmp endp

delete_word proc word_start:dword, word_end:dword, word_len:dword
        pushad
        mov esi, word_end
        inc esi
        mov edi, word_start
        mov ecx, word_len
        inc ecx
    rep movsb
        popad
        ret
delete_word endp
; ---------------------------------------------------------------

end main
```